# Ruby Open-URI - specify content type?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I'm trying

```
io = open(uri, {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER})
```

the result is not what I want.

```
io.content_type
=> "text/html"
```

Can I specify I want `"application/pdf"`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
io = open(uri, "Content-Type" => "application/pdf", ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```